# Copy paste column if certain text is detected

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a code, but it's not working. The code needs insert a column before the column containing "X" in row 2 & to copy-paste as values in the column to the left.
And to continue the same process looped for other worksheets within the workbook. I'm unable to run the code. The X will be in multiple worksheets in different columns, but always in Row 2.
Help in this will be highly appreciated.
[WorksheetView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Vfm.png)

```
  Sub insert_column()

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.StatusBar = False

  With ThisWorkbook

  bsheets = 0

  For A = 1 To Sheets.Count

  If If Len(Sheets(A).Name) < 5 Then
  Sheets(A).Cells = Cells.Find(What:="X", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
  xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False_, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    dcol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    bsheets = bsheets + 1

    Columns(dcol).Select

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Columns(dcol + 1).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Columns(dcol).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

   End If

   Next A

   Exit Sub

   Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.StatusBar = True

   End With

   End Sub
```

Comment: Does "& to copy-paste as values in the column to the left" mean to copy the transposed row 2 to the newly inserted column? Does that "X" appear only once, and the loop can be exited when it has been found?

Comment: I do not have too much time. I will post an answer, supposing that my above assumption is correct...

Comment: The X will appear on every 1 worksheet once

Comment: Then, test my answer! It should do what (I understood) you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub FindX()
 Dim w As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, i As Long, valX As Variant

 Set w = ActiveWorkbook 'use here your workbook...
 For Each sh In w.Worksheets
    lastCol = sh.Cells(2, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        If sh.Cells(2, i).Value = "X" Then
            valX = sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, 1), sh.Cells(2, lastCol)).Value
            sh.Cells(2, i).EntireColumn.Insert
            sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, i), sh.Cells(lastCol, i)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(valX)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru! This works with my code now after a light adjustment. You're the best!!

Comment: @JRF: Welcome! Was the "adjustment" need well described in your question and I missed it? Or you only changed "X" with something else?

Comment: You got it right. It worked without any issue. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Then, will it be a problem to press the left side check in order to consider the code like Answer, when/if you will have more then 15 reputation ?

Comment: I look forward to upvote you once the reputation level has been reached.